# ExtJS 3 export textarea content to a text file

Tags: extjs, textarea, export

I need to export the contents of an ExtJS TextArea to a text file. I searched around the documentation but I didn't find anything related to a textarea. Is this possible?

It would be also ideal to prepare the filename as well together with the ability to export the textarea content to the file.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to do this with a serverside technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just save something from JS file into any place on user's local computer file system. It's huge security hole and it's just doesn't work this way. You have couple options however:

- Send this information to your server and provide user with a link to a file. User clicks that link server will respond with the information - browser saves that data. You can even make so content will automatically be downloaded by the browser (well, by most of them anyway)
- Or you can ask user to right click and copy this information into the clipboard.

Comment: There are some ways around it, like using base64 for instance but it is very browser dependent and you cannot control the filename so I ended up doing it serverside.